Next.js amp and non-amp pages route
I have a question. I made a website and I want to add AMP functionality to this website. While normal pages (page.tsx) are loaded on PCs, I want a separate page for AMP (for example, pageamp.tsx) to be loaded on phones. Is this possible?
Next.js 2 different web pages, AMP compatible and non AMP compatible, under the same folder
